# How to call reduce on an array of objects to return the sum of values based on a name in that object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the sum of male and female for a county. That is for instance, if "Bomi" all male and female in the same object with "Bomi" should be added. But I don't understand why it's not working.

```
let population = [{
            "county": "Bomi",
            "district": "Dowein",
            "male": 6589,
            "female": 6599
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi",
            "district": "Klay",
            "male": 11884,
            "female": 11513
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa",
            "district": "Senjeh",
            "male": 15442,
            "female": 14585
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa",
            "district": "Suehn Mecca ",
            "male": 9025,
            "female": 8482
        }]

 let countyPopTotal = POPULATION.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, index) {
            if (accumulator.indexOf(currentValue.county) === -1) {
              let sum = 0;
               sum += currentValue.male + currentValue.female
                accumulator.push(sum)
            }
            return accumulator
        }, [])
        console.log(countyPopTotal);
```

Comment: it is population not POPULATION

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use an Object instead of an Array to collect the counts for the different countries:

```js
let population = [{
            "county": "Bomi",
            "district": "Dowein",
            "male": 6589,
            "female": 6599
        },
        {
            "county": "Bomi",
            "district": "Klay",
            "male": 11884,
            "female": 11513
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa",
            "district": "Senjeh",
            "male": 15442,
            "female": 14585
        },
        {
            "county": "Lofa",
            "district": "Suehn Mecca ",
            "male": 9025,
            "female": 8482
        }]

 let countyPopTotal = population.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, index) {
            if (!accumulator[currentValue.county]) accumulator[currentValue.county]=0
            accumulator[currentValue.county] += currentValue.male + currentValue.female
            return accumulator
        }, {})
        console.log(countyPopTotal);
 
 // Or, if you can get along with shorter names, everything can be written in a single line:
 let tots = population.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.county]=(a[c.county]||0)+c.male+c.female,a),{})
console.log(tots);
```

Comment: Hi Carsten Massmann, can you explain this code a bit. 

```
let tots = population.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c.county]=(a[c.county]||0)+c.male+c.female,a),{})
console.log(tots);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.reduce function to get sum of population by gender in a county.

```
population.reduce((acc, value) => {
    const county = value.county;

    if (!acc[county]) {
        acc[county] = {};
    }

    const countyMales = acc[county].male || 0;
    const countyFemales = acc[county].female || 0;
    const updatedMales = countyMales + value.male;
    const updatedFemales = countyFemales + value.female;
    acc[county] = { male: updatedMales, female: updatedFemales, total: updatedMales + updatedFemales };

    return acc;
}, {})
```

Output will look like:

```
{
    "Bomi": {
        "male": 18473,
        "female": 18112,
        "total": 36585
    },
    "Lofa": {
        "male": 24467,
        "female": 23067,
        "total": 47534
    }
}
```

You can then access any of those values easily.